# vb.net - Task-based SQL Class to process SQL queries "one by one"

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

the community!

As my issue has been giving me a lot of headaches in the past two days, I finally decided to reach to you guys for help.

I am maintaining a fairly complex application in vb.net, which has some Classes that are running in the background separately from the main form. We are using the Amazon database to store our data, and during the runtime, the application makes a lot of different queries to the database, ranging from INSERT, DELETE, SELECT, etc.

Here is my SQLControl Class that handles all the queries:

```
Public Class MySQLControl
Public DBCon As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(GetRDSConnectionString()) ' Database connection
Private DBCmd As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand 'MySQL command

Public DBDA As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter 'MySQL Data Adapter
Public DBDT As DataTable 'SQL Data table

Public Params As New List(Of MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter) 'Query parameters

'QUERY STATISTICS
Public RecordCount As Integer
Public Exception As String

Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String, Optional ReturnIdentity As Boolean = False)
    'RESET QUERY STATS
    RecordCount = 0
    Exception = ""

    Try
        DBCon.Open()

        ' CREATE DB COMMAND
        DBCmd = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(Query, DBCon)

        ' LOAD PARAMS INTO DB COMMAND
        Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))

        'EXECUTE COMMAND AND FILL DATASET
        DBDT = New DataTable
        DBDA = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(DBCmd)

        RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)

        If ReturnIdentity = True Then
            Dim ReturnQuery As String = "SELECT @@IDENTITY As LastID;"
            DBCmd = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(ReturnQuery, DBCon)
            DBDT = New DataTable
            DBDA = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(DBCmd)
            RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exception = "ExecQuery Error: " & vbNewLine & ex.Message
        If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
    Finally
        'Clear param list
        Params.Clear()

        'CLOSE CONNECTION
        If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

'ADD PARAMS
Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
    Dim NewParam As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter(Name, Value)
    Params.Add(NewParam)
End Sub

'ERROR CHECKING
Public Function HasExpetion(Optional Report As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Exception) Then Return False
    If Report = True Then MsgBox(Exception, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "EXCEPTION")
    Return True
End Function
......
End Class
```

This works very well, and as an example:

```
sql.AddParam("@build", ThisPCBuild)
sql.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO meta_data_table (App_Version) VALUES (@build);")
```

Or here's another:

```
sql.ExecQuery("SELECT test_column FROM test_table;")
```

And this works perfectly well. But, I have been getting errors like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", or occasionally the application does not insert or update the database when it should. I also sometimes get an error stating that "Cannot open a connection while the connection is in connecting state".

I figured out that the issue is happening because all the different queries were racing to insert, update, delete, select the database, and it apparently happens that one query did not finish its job in the ExecQuery subroutine (until the connection is closed) but another query already came and started adding parameters or updating the database, and that's when I get errors like the ones above.

I am curious if there is a way to run queries "one by one"? I have been reading about Threads and Tasks, but can't figure out how to implement them in this case. Tasks are confusing, because if I add "(Of String)" I can get a string only from the Task Async function, but not record count, for example. Please note that the application makes many various calls (at least 10 per minute) to the Queries, but it happens that some queries run at the same time...

Hoping that I am clear on my issue, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to serialize the calls to the object, you should look into the `lock` statement.

Comment: I tried to lock the ExecQuery sub by using the SyncLock without luck.

Comment: As already said thousands of times, a _do it all_ database class is just an infinite source of bugs and in the long run is just a waste of time. For example, this code keeps a reference to a disposable object like the connection. This is another problem that will bite you in future. I suggest you to spend some time to investigate the many ORM libraries around that are well maintained and tested in many different contexts.

Comment: you have basically tw query some that do and have no replay and those how give back information, after that you have stored procedures that can ahve multiple tables as answer, which has to be treated diffferently, as long as you don't a heterogen query system, it will be a pain to put it all in ine class.

Comment: You could consider setting up a producer-consumer model, probably mediated by a `BlockingCollection` or related class (this already has the locking built into it so you don't need to focus on getting that right).  This can work with a task-based setup if you desire, in which case you'll need to look at `TaskCompletionSource` as that's what you'll need on the consumer side to be able to return a result.  If you may have different kinds of return values, then you'll lose the ability to enforce type safety through the type system and will need to work with `Object`.

Comment: You don't need any crazy smart locking/mutex solution if you'd just make a new Connection/Command/Adapter, and not have it in a shared context, every time you want to do a DB-anything. I've no idea why people avoid making new database conenctions, and go crazy trying to reuse stuff; opening a DB conenction is leasing permanently open connections from a pool and takes nanoseconds, it's not making a new TCP connection that takes seconds. Do as MS recommend (make a new everything every time, unless you know you have a thousand inserts to do, in which case make a new one, do 1000 and dispose it)